# How to use an email template through code in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo, email-templates

I've created a model named `event` and another one named `event.participant`. The model `event` has the field `participants`, which is a `One2many` field pointing to `event.participant` (*event 1:N event.participant*).

In the form of `event` I have a button *Confirm event*, with the next code:

```
@api.multi
def confirm_event(self):
    for event in self:
        return event.participants.notify(composition_mode='mass_mail')
```

The method `notify` was created by me in the model `event.participant`. What it does is to open the `mail.compose.message` wizard form you see each time you want to send a mail from Odoo (with the fields *from*, *to*, *subject*, *body*, *template_id*, etc). Here is the code of the method `notify`:

```
@api.multi
def notify(self, composition_mode=False):
    form_view_id = self.env.ref(
        'mail.email_compose_message_wizard_form').id
    ctx = self.env.context.copy()
    if composition_mode:
        ctx.update({
            'default_composition_mode': composition_mode,
        })
    result = {
        'name': 'Send Mail',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'views': [(form_view_id, 'form'), ],
        'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
        'context': ctx,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
    }
    return result
```

Now I'm going to show an example of the behaviour I'm getting with this code:

I have an event with ID 16. That event has two participants with IDs 21 and 22. I go to the form of the event and click on the button *Confirm event*. The wizard form to send the email is opened rightly. But, then, I select an email template (this email template applies to `event.participant` model), and click on *Send mail*.

I get a template renderization error. I guess I know why I'm getting that error:

The `active_model` at the wizard form is **event** and the `active_ids` is **[16]**, while they should be **event.participant** and **[21, 22]** respectively. So, as the email template selected applies to `event.participant`, the variables inside it fail. For example, the *to* of the email template is `${object.email|safe}`. That `object` variable is replaced by the record **16** of `event`. The model `event` doesn't have a field named `email`, so it generates a renderization error.

I cannot create a template which applies to `event`, because it would be a nosense (how can I indicate in the *to* of the template all the email addresses of the participants?).

I have to use a template which applies to `event.participant`, but I need to have the right `active_model` and `active_ids` in the moment of the renderization. I tried to modify these variables directly in the context, but I give another error.

How can I achieve my purpose? Is there any easier mode to do that? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code:

```python
@api.multi
def confirm_event(self):
    for event in self:
        return event.participants.notify()


@api.multi
def notify(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    form_view_id = self.env.ref('mail.email_compose_message_wizard_form')
    ctx = dict(default_model='event.participants',
               default_res_id=self.id,
               default_composition_mode='mass_mail',
               )
    return {
        'name': 'Send Mail',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
        'views': [(form_view_id.id, 'form'), ],
        'view_id': form_view_id.id,
        'context': ctx,
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Jainik! But I can't use `self.ensure_one()` and `self.id` here, because `notify` is usually called from a recordset of several participants (that's why I need to use mass mail composition model). The loop inside `confirm_event` method ensures that in `notify` there will be a recordset of a single record, but this method `notify` is also called from other methods that can't do a loop inside.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, but I think it's crazy. Finally I've modified the `active_model` and the `active_ids` in the context, I told it was giving an error, so I've also modified the `active_id` variable. Now it works. So I've added these lines to the `ctx` update in the `notify` method:

```
ctx.update({
    'default_composition_mode': composition_mode,
    'active_model': self._name,
    'active_ids': self._ids,
    'active_id': self._ids[0],
})
```

In spite of being working as I want, I think this is an awful workaround, and I'm pretty sure that it must be a better solution to solve my problem.

If anyone knows it, please, post the answer here!

Answer (score 2):

If you send *view_id* in to it, than it will open/redirect as given form view.

You may try this solution:

```
@api.multi
def notify(self, composition_mode=False):
    form_view_id = self.env.ref('mail.email_compose_message_wizard_form', False)
    ctx = self.env.context.copy()
    if composition_mode:
        ctx.update({
            'default_composition_mode': composition_mode,
        })
    result = {
        'name': _('Send Mail'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'views': [(form_view_id, 'form')],
        'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
        'view_id': form_view_id and form_view_id.id,
        'context': ctx,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
    }
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you @Odedra! But with this code the active model in `mail.compose.message` wizard form is still `event` when I click on `confirm_event`, instead of `participant` (the model I need to be the active one).